# GridView AllowPaging = true but implement my own paging but use the asp.net pager

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

ASP.net webforms here, if I set AllowPaging=true and implement my own paging mechanism where I am fetching say 25 records at a time.  I'd like to be able to use the default gridview pager, but it seems to be having trouble setting the number of pages.  Is this an internal calculation where the ENTIRE dataset has to be binded for it to determine this calculation?

For instance, assume a query has 1000 rows and I want to only fetch 25 of them at a time.  Does the gridview pager need to execute the 1000 rows as its datasource in order to get the correct number of pages (buttons) to display.  I cant find a property allowing me to specify the number of pages, they all seem to be read only (get methods).

I want to avoid building my own pager...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Effective Paging with GridView Control in ASP.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125541/Effective-Paging-with-GridView-Control-in-ASP-NET) Article describes how to implement the pagination where your gridview requests the data only for the page that is visible.

Don't be put off by the fact that the database query is executed twice. Once for the total count and another to get the page's data. For applications with high traffic or a lot of data, this approach is still more efficient than getting everything, loading into a gridview (and the view state!), sending it to the end user, and the browser loading it on the screen :).

Answer (score 0):

That's where virtual paging comes in.

Set `AllowCustomPaging` to `true`.

In `PageIndexChanging` event, set `VirtualItemCount` and `PageIndex` to the proper value.

Put only the 25 rows in the `DataSource`, do a `DataBind` as usual, you're done.

Comment: AllowCustomPaging is for DataGrid not GridView. DataGrid AllowCustomPaging still Loads all the data, but only a segment of it is bound to the control.

Comment: @rommik Oh, my bad. You can inherit your own grid from `GridView` that can do that, though. Or create your own `IList` implementation that's sparse - it will report 2000 items, but will only have the 25 at the right spots.